# Escape Left Bracket C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, escaping

I have a string in the following format:

```
prm.Add( "blah", "blah" );
```

I am looking to use regex to extract the first "blah". 
To do this I am carving the front half off and then the back half.

The regex I'm using to get rid of "prm.Add( " is:

```
"prm.Add\([ ]*"
```

Other threads seem to indicate that escape characters before paranthesis would be acceptable. However VS complains that I have an invalid escape charcter sequence "(". 
If I use:

```
"prm.Add([ ]*"
```

The application errors as there is no closing paranthesis.

I realise I can get around this by using Regex.Escape on the "prm.Add(". But this isn't really very elegant.

Have I got my regex syntax wrong or does VS2010 not accept escapes of brackets?

Comment: Side note - you'll want to escape the `.` also, unless you want to match any character at that position.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are trying to use this regular expression as part of the search within the Visual Studio IDE - or as part of an RegEx class within your code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to escape the backslash as well for the compiler to understand: `"prm.Add\\([ ]*"` or `@"prm.Add\([ ]*"`

Otherwise the compiler couldn't understand things like `"\n"` - what does the author want? A line break or the string "\n" as-is?

But I'd try to make it more dynamic, e.g. not assuming a space character being there.

Comment: Did the trick thanks very much! Also I was under the impression that standard usage of * would imply 0 or more so would get rid of any whitespace even if it didn't exist?

Comment: Yes, but there's even a special character class for whitespaces: `\s` which will match any white space (space, tab, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

When you escape in patterns (which are strings) you have to use two escape sequences:

```
"prm.Add\\([ ]*"
```

This is because if you only use one escape, the system tries to find a character that evaluates to `\(`, that doesn't exist - others that you surely know are e.g. `\r` or `\n`.

So, by using two `\`, you actually escape the `\` - leaving it in the pattern that is interpreted. And inside that pattern, you then esapce the regex-meaning of `(`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that, when escaping a string in the IDE, you are escaping something so that the *compiler* understands the escaping. What you want is that the REGEX object understands your string.

You need the regex object to get `prm.Add\([ ]*`.

However, the backlash (`\`) is a escape character, so the compiler will try to escape "(", which he doesn't knows how to. So... you need to escape the backlash itself:

```
prm.Add\\([ ]*
```

The compiler process this string and transforms `\\` into `\`. Which leads to what you want, since the Regex will now get a string formed by `prm.Add\([ ]*`.

One way to understand this is that if you were reading the regex from a file or from a user input, only one backlash would be needed, since the compiler isn't any longer processing it (the string is acquired in run-time as opposed to compile-time in hard-coding it).